# Perl mysql, why does this fetchrow_array not work?

Tags: mysql, perl

I have Perl code like so:

```
$pre = $dbh->prepare("select distinct skills from people");
$pre->execute;

my @preList;
while (my $row = $pre->fetchrow_array()) {
    push (@preList,$row);
}
print "Pre list: $_" foreach @preList;
```

When I try the exact same statement in sql it works perfectly, but when I run this program it prints out nothing (suggesting an empty `@preList`). I am probably doing something very stupid, but cannot see it. I have used this format for getting data before, which works perfectly. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: You really need `error handling`

Comment: @sputnick - We don't see the connect, there might be a RaiseError there, but I am doubtfull.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now you are doing, `fetchrow_array` which returns a list but you are trying to store it in a scalar, you can either change it to `fetchrow_arrayref` or change `$row` to `@row`, or change `my $row` to `my ($row)`.

Comment: perfect! using `@row` worked like a charm. I'm puzzled, though, as I've used that exact format before and it worked without `@row`. maybe there was a column type difference or something :/

Comment: no, perl won't return an array in scalar context (in fact perl never returns arrays, only lists).  @bladepanthera: see my answer for the likely culprit

Comment: @ysth - Perhaps it depends on the DBD. Just tested w/DBD::Oracle, and selecting one column works fine w/scalar context. I would not depend on this universally though, as the docs warn against it.

Comment: @runrig: but was the value selected false?  it should *not* depend on the DBD unless the select returns multiple columns.

Answer (score 4):

When you say:

```
while (my $row = $pre->fetchrow_array()) {
```

a value is returned from a row, assigned into $row, then tested for truth.
As soon as a skills value that is false is returned, the loop will terminate, without putting that value in @preList.  If the first row of results has a skills that is NULL or "" or "0", you will see the results you are seeing.

Changing to:

```
while (my ($row) = $pre->fetchrow_array()) {
```

(or using @row, as others have suggested), a value is still returned from each row, and assigned into $row, but instead of the value being tested for truth, the number of elements returned from fetchrow_array is tested for truth (and fetchrow_array returns an empty list when it runs out of result rows, so this number is 1 for each row of results and then 0 to terminate the loop).    This happens because while() expects a scalar to test, so gives the assignment scalar context, and in perl, a list assignment in scalar context returns a count of elements on the right side of the assignment, specifically so that code such as this will just work.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pre = $dbh->prepare("select distinct skills from people");
$pre->execute;

my @preList;
while (my $row = $pre->fetch()) {
    push (@preList,$row);
}
foreach @preList{
    print "Pre list row: " . join(',',@$_);
}
```

or:

```
$pre = $dbh->prepare("select distinct skills from people");
$pre->execute;

my $preList = $pre->fetchall_arrayref();

foreach @$preList{
    print "Pre list row: " . join(',',@$_);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try replacing `fetchrow_array` in your code with `fetchrow_arrayref`.