# Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at

Tags: sql, perl

I've this error:

> `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at...`

#### This is my code:

```
$queryH= $dbh->prepare($query);
$queryH->execute();
my $i=0;
my $result;
while (@data = $queryH->fetchrow_array()) 
{
    $result=$data[$i];
    if ($result)
    {
        print "$result \n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "Records Not Found!\n";
        last;
    }
    print "\n";
    $i++;
}
print "\n\n";
$queryH->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

What error is there in my code?

The error is on the line:

```
$result=$data[$i];
```

Comment: Sorry...the error is on this line:
  $result=$data[$i];
thanks a lot :D

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12844476/78845) useful.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Or more specifically, what are you trying to accomplish by incrementing `$i`?

Answer (score 1):

You are starting out with `$i=0` and you increment it with each pass of the `while` loop. You look at `$data[$i]` once for each line of database result. So for the first row, you look at `$data[0]`. For the second row of data, you look at `$data[1]` and so on. At some point, your `$i` (which is effectively a rowcount starting at zero) will be higher than the number of fields per row. That produces the error message.

If you put in a `print "$i\n"` in the beginning of the `while` block you will see what I am talking about.